# ASP.NET if statement creating div

Tags: html, asp.net, xslt, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a sidebar menu that creates div's within li's.

The issue I'm having is that if item in the menu is active, it shouldn't create the inactive div before it. ie: it should only have `<li><div></div></li>`, not `<li><div></div><div></div></li>`.

```
      <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) = 0 and EntityID!=$pCatID">
        <div class="inactive">
          <!--<a href="{concat('c-',EntityID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}" style="color:black">-->
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(child::Entity)=0">

              <a href="{concat('c-',EntityID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}" style="color:black">
                <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
              </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="EntityID=$ParentCategoryID">
                  <div class="active">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                  </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

          <!--</a>-->
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
```

That outputs:

```
<li>
  **<div class="inactive">**
    <div class="active">
    Active item
  **</div>**
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="inactive">
  Inactive item
  </div>
</li>
```

What must change in the above code so the inactive div isn't created outside of the active div, and should only be created where it is inactive? I've placed the lines in **'s that shouldn't be there.

I know it has something to do with arranging the `test="EntityID=$ParentCategoryID"` or `if` statement properly but just can't figure it out.

Comment: What variable tells you that an item is active?

Comment: @LenielMacaferi: obviously more code to it, but the general question of how do I stop that empty div being created outside the active class div? `$ParentCategoryID` is the one that is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this version?

```
  <xsl:if test="number(ParentEntityID) = 0 and EntityID!=$pCatID">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(child::Entity)=0">
          <a href="{concat('c-',EntityID,'-',SEName,'.aspx')}" style="color:black">
            <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
          </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="EntityID=$ParentCategoryID">
              <div class="active">
                <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <div class="inactive">
              <xsl:value-of select="$eName"/>
               </div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just now the inactive div is missing from the inactive items :)

Comment: Perfect! See I did exactly what you did, by placing the inactive div within the `when test="count(child::Entity)=0` statement rather than outside, but that didn't work :) your fix works :D Thank you!!

Comment: Nice to know it works! That's what we're after... make things work as expected. :D